# Bind Real Time Notifications in Laravel Blade as alert

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, broadcasting, pusher-js

In my web app I want to notify some specific users when some task is created from admin. This should be real time. Therefore I used laravel pusher. But it not make any sense. I want to fix this.

**My Controller :**

```
        public function add(Request $request){
            $data = $request->all();
            $tasks = Todo::create($data);

            //send notofications 
            $notifyTo = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereIn('slug', [ 'manager'   ]);})->get();
            foreach ($notifyTo as $notifyUser) {
                $notifyUser->notify(new TaskCreated($tasks));
            }
        }
```

**My TaskCreated Notification Class**

```
public function via($notifiable)
   {
      return ['broadcast'];
   }

public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->tasks->task
    ];
}
```

**My Pusher Debug Console**

[image: Pusher Debug Console]

This is my boostrap.js

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key:'bf6e79cce8gfggf548fb2c5e9',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    forceTLS: true
});
```

and this is my front end

```
<script>
  var userId = $('meta[name="userId"]').attr('content');
    Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });

  </script>
```

Config/broadcasting.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            //'options' => [
                //'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                //'encrypted' => true,
               // 'host' => '127.0.0.1',
               // 'port' => 6004,
               // 'scheme' => 'http'
            //],

            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

I want to alert title of notification in my laravel web app. How can it possible ? Please suggest a solution for front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Notifiable` trait in User model. After that, you need to specify what channel the broadcast will use. To make it unique, append **user_id** at the end of a constant **channel_name** like so:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The channels the user receives notification broadcasts on.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {
        return 'users.'.$this->id;
    }
}
```

On the frontend, you need to use a package called `Laravel Echo`. You can listen to your broadcasts on the front end using the **Laravel Echo** like so:

```
Echo.private('users.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });
```

Reference Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#listening-for-notifications

Comment: Hi. I added the `Notifiable` trait to User Model and `receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn` function to User Model.And also put the `Laravel Echo` to the front end also.  But in the console. I don't get anything. Its empty.

Comment: Did you install laravel echo and configure it? what are using for broadcasting from backend? Try running `php artisan queue:work`. Also open your console and check for any errors. Laravel echo will throw some erros if connection is unsuccessful.

Comment: I did install and configure it. How do i validate it if I installed Echo correctly ? And also checked errors. There are no any errors in console. I updated my `boostrap.js` and front end in the question. Please refer it also

Comment: Ok, seems you configured it properly. Next step is to check what you are using for backend broadcasting. I know two of the popular ones, Pusher and Laravel-Websockets. For laravel-websockets to broadcast, you have to do `php artisan websockets:serve` and `php artisan queue:work` in two different terminals.

Comment: Hi I am using Pusher as backend broadcasting. In the pusher debug console. event is working successfully as attached images in my question

Comment: Also, my bad. Since you have added `receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn` to your model you should listen to `Echo.private('users.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });`

Comment: I add it to the question. Please refer

Comment: I assume you are trying this on production since `forceTLS: true` for laravel echo? Fix the echo channel to `'users.' + userId` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213215/discussion-between-uzair-riaz-and-anushka-deshan).

Comment: What if I remove `forceTLS:true`. also tried fixing channel to `'users.' + userId`. But nothing changed.

Comment: could you join the chat if its not a problem? I can help you better there. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213215/discussion-between-uzair-riaz-and-anushka-deshan

Comment: Finally Its done bro. In the `Routes/Channels.php` changes it as `Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});` .

Comment: right, for private channels, authentication is required. Glad you could solve it!

Comment: Bro. Do we have any method to work multiple private channels in above example case ?

Comment: lets chat at https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/zt-eau36fgx-k1KWjR7fmNdqfvlJouderw. so I can understand what you are trying to do better.